# lightdm set an wrong DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

Tags: systemd, awesome-wm, dbus

I'm using archlinux and lightdm+lightdm-gtk-greeter+aweome as my work environment.

I found my DBUS_SESSION_BUS_SESSION is not properly setup, when I enabled lightdm as my login manager.This environment is set to /tmp/dbus-xxxxx while correct value should be /run/user/xxx/dbus.

But if I disabled lightdm as my login manager, just boot to command line mode, after create .xinirc(content is `exec awesome`) under ~ directory.Reboot and login to system, if I start Xorg with startx command, DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is properly set to /run/user/xxx/dbus.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem ?